# Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver() ? in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

**I get the following error :**

**"Are you missing a call to unregister receiver"**

```
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: 

Activity com.apps.activities.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.wwhere.fragment.MainRecyclerViewFragment$1@44d50ba8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()? at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:809)

at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1478)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1458)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1452)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
```

**My code is :**

```
private BroadcastReceiver actionConversation = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        setAdapter();
    }
};

private void registerBroadCasts() {
    IntentFilter intentConnection = new IntentFilter(Constants.CONVERSATION_SCREEN);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(actionConversation, intentConnection);
}
```

And i call **`registerBroadCasts()`** in `onCreate` method.

Comment: @Kinjal if you are working with `BroadcastReceiver` you have to `Unregister` that receiver in `OnDestroy()` method of Activity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you are using `GCM` in your application.

In the `activity` where you are registering a device to `GCM`,write the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    try{
        if(mHandleMessageReceiver!=null)
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

    }catch(Exception e){}

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

where **mHandleMessageReceiver** is the instance of the **BroadcastReceiver**.