# Error: YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver ... Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I uses YoutubeServie API to play youtube video in my Android application. However when I exit my activity, I found the below crash log showing, even my App still works.

```
02-28 15:54:02.081 20374-20374/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.youtube.api.service.YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.audiofocus.HeadsetPlugReceiver@a843e7c that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                   android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.google.android.youtube.api.service.YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.audiofocus.HeadsetPlugReceiver@a843e7c that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:898)
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:699)
                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1637)
                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1617)
                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1611)
                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:488)
                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.service.PlaybackService.<init>(PlaybackService.java:5034)
                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.PlayerInjector$12.create(PlayerInjector.java:1602)
                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.youtube.common.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:136)
                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.PlayerInjector.getPlaybackService(PlayerInjector.java:575)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.ApiPlayer.moveToForeground(ApiPlayer.java:493)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.ApiPlayer.<init>(ApiPlayer.java:150)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.service.jar.ApiPlayerService.<init>(ApiPlayerService.java:131)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.service.jar.ApiPlayerFactoryService$1.run(ApiPlayerFactoryService.java:86)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-28 15:54:02.088 20374-20374/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.youtube.api.service.YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.audiofocus.AudioBecomingNoisyReceiver@379c216f that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                   android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.google.android.youtube.api.service.YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.audiofocus.AudioBecomingNoisyReceiver@379c216f that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:898)
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:699)
                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1637)
                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1617)
                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1611)
                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:488)
                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.service.PlaybackService.<init>(PlaybackService.java:4043)
                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.PlayerInjector$12.create(PlayerInjector.java:1602)
                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.youtube.common.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:136)
                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.PlayerInjector.getPlaybackService(PlayerInjector.java:575)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.ApiPlayer.moveToForeground(ApiPlayer.java:493)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.ApiPlayer.<init>(ApiPlayer.java:150)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.service.jar.ApiPlayerService.<init>(ApiPlayerService.java:131)
                                                       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.service.jar.ApiPlayerFactoryService$1.run(ApiPlayerFactoryService.java:86)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

None of the code are from mine app, but all are in the library. I didn't register any receiver in my code, so can't unregister anything in my fragment that works with the youtubeservice.

I think the issue is similar to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/6gzpwkaRgoE but no answer given. Any idea how to get rid of this internal crash of youtube.api.service?

Comment: Hello Elye , Did you fixed this issue. This is Issue is annoying me crazy. Kindly help me if possible.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix this issue ? Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Hi, i'm facing same issue. Have you solved your's?

Comment: The YouTube Player API is often tricky and tedious to use, for this reason I've built an open source alternative. It's based on WebView and won't give any of this problems. https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not manually register any receiver, an activity may register it to use it in some way on the current activity. I think you should need to call **unregisterReceiver()** method on **onPause()**.

Please be aware that onDestroy() and onStop() are not guaranteed to be called.
If onPause() will be called, then the Activity is no longer in the foreground.

> **OnStop():**
>
> Called when you are no longer visible to the user. You will next receive either onRestart(), onDestroy(), or nothing, depending on later user activity.
>   **Note that this method may never be called, in low memory situations where the system does not have enough memory to keep your activity's process running after its onPause() method is called.**
>
> For more information, here's the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29

Fortunately, I also found some stackoverflow items that you can refer to:

- [Activity has leaked IntentReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357566/activity-has-leaked-intentreceiver-that-was-originally-registered-here-are-you)
- [Unable to play youtube video in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806530/unable-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-app)
- [Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver() ? in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272347/are-you-missing-a-call-to-unregisterreceiver-in-android)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks @rod. However, there's nothing I can place as argument in my unregisterReceiver(...) function. I have seen all the above links, and none have the answer. The second one, just guide one how to get the Youtube API going, but the internal crashes still happens... On my side, I have the youtube playing fine. Just the internal log of the internal crash always happen. I want to know "what" to "unregister".

Comment: Hi @Elye. Based on you console log, there is AudioBecomingNoisyReceiver and HeadsetPlugReceiver being used. I  tried to search something on this and it leads me to this [link](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2013/06/android-detect-when-headsetheadphones.html). Is there any of your code referring to this?

Comment: Nope. Not using it. Perhaps it's the Youtube API SDK using it internally, and it's beyond our control :(. Suspect somewhere in `com.google.android.libraries.youtube.player.service.PlaybackService.`  Beside, it's not open source... so can't dig into it to check out